# Caesar cipher in C only works sometimes?

Tags: c, algorithm, encryption

I'm having trouble with C. I've only been learning it for a few weeks, and this algorithm is killing me. Whenever I input a sentence, some letters will be shifted k times, others k+1. I have no idea what could be causing this error.

`s` = the text I wish to encode
`k` = my key

```
char s[] = "…";
int k = …;

for (int i=0, n=strlen(s); i<n;i++)
{
    if (s[i] >= 'A' && s[i]<='Z') //handles all capital letters
    {
        if ((s[i]+k)>'Z') //in case of a wraparound
        {
            printf("%c", s[i]+(k-('Z'-'A')));
        }
        else //when there is no wraparound
        {
            printf("%c", s[i]+ k);
        }
    }
    else if (s[i]>='a' && s[i]<='z') //handles all lowercase letters
    {
        if ((s[i]+k)>'z') //in case of a wraparound
        {
            printf("%c", s[i]+(k-('z'-'a')));
        }
        else //when there is no wraparound
        {
            printf("%c", s[i]+k);
        }
    }
    else //handles everything that is not a letter
    {
        printf("%c", s[i]);
    }
}
printf("\n");
```

Comment: Working fine for me. Could you show us your input for which you are getting wrong result?

Comment: Your last `else` clause seems to be missing `+ k` in the `printf`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch That seems to be on purpose, as it catches non alphabetical symbols

Comment: What input(s) don't produce a good output?

Answer (score 1):

In 2 places, you are subtracting the wrong amount.  You want to subtract 26, not 25.

```
// printf("%c", s[i]+(k-('Z'-'A')));/   
printf("%c", s[i]+(k-('Z'-'A' + 1))); 
...
// printf("%c", s[i]+(k-('z'-'a'))); 
printf("%c", s[i]+(k-('z'-'a' + 1)));
```

Comment: +1: This is correct.  Given `k=3` as in the original Caesar cipher and input string `"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnoparstuvwxyz0123.',!@"`,  the original code produces the output `DEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZBCDdefghijklmnopqrsduvwxyzbcd0123.',!@`, where you can see that `A` and `a` do not appear in the output, and with the fix, it produces `DEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCdefghijklmnopqrsduvwxyzabc0123.',!@`, which shows the complete alphabet twice.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler  bene facis! - but just had to add: [I came, I saw, I shifted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veni,_vidi,_vici).